# Properly selecting and filtering elements in variable HTML structure with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML fragment with multiple elements (mostly of the same type (here for example I use SPAN), but also a few others) that may be enclosed within a DIV, but not always. Basically, sometimes I have a single root element (the DIV), sometimes I have multiple elements at the same level. What is the proper way to select all of these specified elements (SPAN) with jQuery?

*Clarification Update*: This way of selecting should succeed for both cases listed below

To give an example, the following code segment shows you two possible structures for my HTML fragment.

```
var test1 = "<div><span></span><span></span><div></div></div>";
var test2 = "<span></span><span></span><div></div>";
alert($(test1).filter("span").length);
alert($(test2).filter("span").length);
```

Naturally, the first filter returns 0, whereas the second returns 2. I know one way to 'solve' this would be to encapsulate my fragment within a DIV, on which I then run my filter, however I'm curious to know if there's a better solution.

*Update 2:* What I could do (as mentioned in the paragraph above) is something like the following code, which works for both cases:

```
alert($("<div></div>").append(test2).find("span").length);
```

Comment: I would think there has to be a way to do this, but for the life of me I can't figure what it might be...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to find out how many spans are contained in a element you would use

```
.siblings()
```

so say you have this:

```
<div><span></span><span></span><div></div></div>
```

if you want to see how many spans are contained in the div you would

```
$('div').siblings("span").length;
```

and if you just wanted to know how many elements are contained in that div you would just remove the parameter from siblings like this:

```
$('div').siblings().length;
```

Comment: I think he understands that, but wants one test that would return the number of spans from either example.

Comment: jbruno is correct, I want to find a solution that helps me in both cases that I listed